# Background image doesnt fit

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, background-image

Im putting an image to my first asp.net core project like a background , but when I put it, it gets also like a footer , I want to be between the header and the footer.

[a picture of the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZS6Y.jpg)

My shared _Layout code:

```
@using CarRental.Common
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@this.ViewData["Title"] - @GlobalConstants.SystemName</title>

    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link href="~/css/site.min.css" rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">@GlobalConstants.SystemName</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Settings" asp-action="Index">Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @this.RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - @GlobalConstants.SystemName - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @this.RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The home page code , where I put the background

```
@using CarRental.Common
@{
    this.ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(/images/background-home.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
</style>

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4" style="color:gold">Welcome to ElisCar! </h1>
</div>
```

I think that I have to add something to the home index.cshtml to fix my problem , thanks

Comment: Try the background on `<div class="container">` only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your footer a background colour, like your header e.g.

```
.footer {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

or add the bg-white class to your `<footer>` tag:

```
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted bg-white">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set higher value of z-index on footer. Then the footer will show on top of the background-image.